# Pattern Matching Java Regex - "One-or-more" operator

Tags: java, regex

How is the "one-or-more" operator used in regex for Java? For example, I want to match this:

( (a) (b) (c) ) - matches

( (a) ) - matches

where a,b,c are any characters or digits

The basic description of this expression is sets of parentheses within a set of parentheses that contains all of the sets separated by one white space

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: ( [(.+) ]+)  <-- but this doesn't work

Comment: Does each set have only one element or is ((a,b,c)) valid?

Comment: You can see some good examples at http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/10-java-regular-expression-examples-you-should-know/

Comment: each set has the same number of elements, but this number is not bounded

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want something like
`\((\(\w*\))+\)`

To make it clearer how it works, expand it a bit visually:

```
\(    # outer bracket
(     # start of group
\(    # inner bracket
\w*   # 0 or more word characters ([0-9a-zA-Z_])
\)    # inner bracket
)     # end of group
+     # and we do that group 1 or more times
\)    # outer bracket
```

Explanation: If you apply * or + or ? to something that was just in (unescaped) brackets, then it is applied to the entire contents of the brackets instead of to just one element.

Whenever I have a regex question I look it up in http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: @Supericy If there are spaces between the brackets, add spaces in the regex too (or `\s*` if you want to be generic about the amount of whitespace)

Comment: @Aneem in Java you need to use two backslashes \\ to pass it to regex engine as one backslash \ since it is also special character in String.

Comment: @Aneem: Java uses backslashes to escape special characters like `\t` and `\n` in its strings - meaning that the backslashes vanish by the time the regular expressions parser sees them. To avoid this, you have to double the backslash count.

Comment: I have a quick followup: let's say instead of \w* I want it to be \w{n} where n is a variable number. Is there a way to do this? (I would not know n beforehand)

Comment: @Aneem You could construct the regex dynamically if you know before running the regex what n is. Failing that, you could run the regex with *, and if it matches check the length of the capture groups to ensure their lengths satisfy your criteria. Regexes don't need to be as conservative as possible, if you're able to check their output in a more programmer friendly way afterwards ;)